# Ingress not binding to Load Balancer

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have my [A record](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/a-record/) on Netlify mapped to my Load Balancer IP Address on Digital Ocean, and it's able to hit the nginx server, but I'm getting a 404 when trying to access any of the apps APIs. I noticed that the status of my Ingress doesn't show that it is bound to the Load Balancer.

[image]

Does anybody know what I am missing to get this setup?

Application Ingress:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: d2d-server
spec:
  rules:
    - host: api.cloud.myhostname.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: d2d-server
                port:
                  number: 443
            path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Application Service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: d2d-server
spec:
  selector:
    app: d2d-server
  ports:
    - name: http-api
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
```

Ingress Controller:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  uid: fc64d9f6-a935-49b2-9d7a-b862f660a4ea
  resourceVersion: '257931'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2021-10-22T05:31:26Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.4
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.0.6
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '1'
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
            defaultMode: 420
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: >-
            k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.0.4@sha256:545cff00370f28363dad31e3b59a94ba377854d3a11f18988f5f9e56841ef9ef
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - '--publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller'
            - '--election-id=ingress-controller-leader'
            - '--controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx'
            - '--configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller'
            - '--validating-webhook=:8443'
            - '--validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert'
            - '--validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key'
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: LD_PRELOAD
              value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 90Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
              drop:
                - ALL
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      serviceAccount: ingress-nginx
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
```

Load Balancer:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.4
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.0.6
  annotations:
    kubernetes.digitalocean.com/load-balancer-id: <LB_ID>
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-enable-proxy-protocol: 'true'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-name: ingress-nginx
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-protocol: https
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: <IP_HIDDEN>
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      appProtocol: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
      nodePort: 31661
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      appProtocol: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
      nodePort: 32761
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  clusterIP: <IP_HIDDEN>
  clusterIPs:
    - <IP_HIDDEN>
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  healthCheckNodePort: 30477
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just needed to add the field [`ingressClassName`](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/basic-configuration/) of `nginx` to the ingress spec.

Comment: Wish I could give you 100 up-votes.That did the trick, and it is _not_ present in DO's tutorial. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

Answer (score 2):

The `kind: ingress` are proxy rules about managing traffic from the **Ingress Controller** to the incluster services. But to achive this, outside traffic needs to reach Ingress Controller.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress

[image: Ingress Flow]

*lets assume that "client" is our Loadbalancer*

So what I assume you want to do is to point your LoadBalancer to the **Ingress Controler** and then, based on you Ingress rules, it will route traffic to you ( in this case ) *d2d* service.

To point a LB to a pod, you need to create a **Service** resource with `spec.type: Loadbalancer` field. I modify an example from digital ocean that should match your needs. Notice the annotation of the Service that can modify the Loadbalancer params, more on this you can find here: https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/docs/controllers/services/annotations.md

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    # @Edit set it to http since no certyficate is provided
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-protocol: "http"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-name: "<YOUR_LB_NAME>"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.4
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.0.6
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
    - name: webhook
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8443
      targetPort: 8443
```

Comment: You are right, I would like traffic to go through the Ingress Controller. It looks like my Digital Ocean cluster came with that LoadBalancer Service by default. I've updated my question to include it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is your **d2d** pod running? Is there a `type:ClisterIP` Service pointing to it? I had never used DigitalOcean so sorry for asking blindly but, we need to find out where the request is dropping.  Can you check if the LB health checks passes ? Are you using http, or https when trying to connect? Does the `spec.rules.host` field match your DNS rule? You can remove the `host` field and check again.  Lookup ingress-controler logs to check if the request hits. Use the `-f` argument to have live logs and try connecting to your pod via the dns as well as the IP address (ip when removed host  field).

Comment: -d2d pod is running. -Service has ClusterIP type. -I see this error in the load balancer events: `Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: failed to build load-balancer request: failed to build TLS part(s) of forwarding rule: must set certificate id or enable tls pass through`

Comment: Ok so it's a certyficate problem. I see that on your ingress service you only got port 443 exposed. You can add additionally add port 80 both in your d2d service and in ingress service. Also try setting on the ingres-controler service an annotation to force use http trafic `service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-protocol: "http"`. 
Check out this site for more options: https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/docs/controllers/services/annotations.md.

Comment: I followed the instructions but still getting 404. I don't see the requests making it to the ingress controller in the pod logs, but I do see `"successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="d2d-server/prod"`.

Comment: The log means that you ingress-controler matched ingress rule with your pod. So we need to focus on you LoadBalancer <-> IngressControler traffic. Did you set that annotation on ingresscontroler service ? Are there any new logs on Loadbalancer? Can you manualy point the Loadbalancer to route HTTP traffic to your http port ingress service? In this case you have to point it to the **31661** NodePort.

Comment: I set the annotation to `http`. If I make a request to `<LB_IP>/health` it registers in the logs, but using the domain name does not. However, I do get an nginx 404 error using the domain, so I think it's hitting the LB. I ran a netcat on port 80 and 443 and both succeeded.
$ nc -vz api.cloud.doortodoorapp.com 80
Connection to api.cloud.doortodoorapp.com 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
$ nc -vz api.cloud.doortodoorapp.com 443
Connection to api.cloud.doortodoorapp.com 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!

Comment: As far as routing http traffic-- it is already pointing to `nodePort: 31661`, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238720/discussion-between-ethan-miller-and-cloudziu).

Comment: @EthanMiller any progress ? Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @matt_j not yet, but we are getting a Nginx 404, so at least we're making it to the load balancer.